# Using dplyr and managing column values

Tags: r

```
State    date      value  value2
Alabama  1-1-2020  121    8800
Alabama  1-1-2020  89     8800
Alabama  1-2-2020  232    8800
Alabama  1-2-2020  311    8800
Alabama  1-3-2020  324    8800
... 
Alabama  1-1-2021  1024   8800
Alaska   1-1-2020  54     3400
Alaska   1-2-2020  43     3400
...
```

I have a dataframe that has repeated values for some of the columns (in this case state and value 2).
I am trying to summarize the above dataframe so that I can have a summary table of something like this:

```
Alabama  1-1-2020  210    8800
Alabama  1-2-2020  543    8800
Alabama  1-3-2020  324    8800
... 
Alabama  1-1-2021  1024   8800
Alaska   1-1-2020  54     3400
Alaska   1-2-2020  43     3400
...
```

Which the values from the value column are added based on each date per state.
I can generate the expected outcome without the "value2" column,

```
df %>% group_by(State, date) %>% summarise(count = sum(value))
```

but once I try to incorporate value2, I don't know how I can go about this.

Answer (score 1):

To keep `Value2` in the output either include `Value2` in `group_by` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(State, date, Value2) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(value))
```

Or extract one particular value in `summarise` :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(State, date) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(value), 
            Value2 = first(Value2))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(State, date) %>%
   mutate(count = sum(value)) %>%
   select(count, Value2)) %>%
   distinct()
```